# Added Timeout to method, and now the first spec always fails

Tags: ruby, rspec

I recently added a timeout to a method that is used by about a dozen different commands in the class. Here is the method:

```
     def exec_mc!(command)
        begin
          Timeout.timeout(30.minutes) do
            library_motion_logger ||= ::Logging.logger["#library_logger.name}::Motion"]
            library_motion_logger.info("Executing mc command 'mc #{command}' ...")
            result = rcm_ssh.execute("/RCM_code/mc #{command}")

            # TODO: Can this be the result.success method instead, which checks for empty stderr also
            # Match the time pattern from mc
            success = result.exit_code.zero?

            MotionCommandResult.new(success, result.execution_time, result.stdout, result.stderr)
          end
        rescue Timeout::Error
          # Something is wrong. Fail out now.
          library_motion_logger.warn("Timed out while waiting for mc command '#{command}'")
          false
        end
      end
```

Now when I run rspec, the first spec fails no matter which one is ran first. If I run a single spec, that also fails. Here is what I am seeing as the failure:

```
1) Library::Motion::MotionCommander#gather behaves like basic motion command with successful result should receive execute("/RCM_code/mc --gather", *(any args)) 1 time
     Failure/Error: @library_gem_logger ||= ::Logging.logger[LIBRARY_GEM_LOGGER_ROOT_DEFAULT]

     Timeout::Error:
       execution expired
```

As you can see, it says that the error occurs while trying to get the logger in the very first line of my begin block. If I remove this line, I get the same error on the next line. So basically I am always getting an error on the first line of the first spec, no matter what. I have tried moving things around and this has held true. What can I do to fix this?

Edit: Here are some of the specs

```
def stub_and_expect_mc(exits = [], stderrs = [], stdouts = [])
    full_command = "/RCM_code/mc #{command}"
    ssh_stub_and_expect(full_command, exits, stderrs, stdouts)
  end

  shared_examples 'basic motion command' do
    context 'with successful result' do
      before :each do
        stub_and_expect_mc(0)
      end
      it { is_expected.to have_attributes(success: true) }
    end
    context 'with unsuccessful result' do
      before :each do
        stub_and_expect_mc(1)
      end
      it { is_expected.to have_attributes(success: false) }
    end
  end

  describe '#random_slot_to_slot' do
    let(:command) { '--randomslot' }
    subject { @library.random_slot_to_slot }
    it_behaves_like 'basic motion command'
  end

  describe '#drawer_to_drawer' do
    # Extra space before --srcdrawer since no mover number is specified
    let(:command) { "--drawertodrawer  --srcdrawer #{src_drawer} --destdrawer #{dest_drawer} --force" }
    let(:src_drawer) { SpectraLibrary::Motion::HydraDrawer.new(0, 0, 1, 0, '', '', 1) }
    let(:dest_drawer) { SpectraLibrary::Motion::HydraDrawer.new(0, 0, 2, 0, '', '', 2) }
    subject { @library.drawer_to_drawer(src_drawer, dest_drawer) }
    it_behaves_like 'basic motion command'
  end
```

Edit 2: Here are the last three times I ran specs, with the rescue removed so you can see the actual failure (otherwise it just shows the result was false)

```
Failures:

  1) SpectraLibrary::Motion::MotionCommander#gather behaves like basic motion command with successful result should receive execute("/RCM_code/mc --gather", *(any args)) 1 time
     Failure/Error: @library_gem_logger ||= ::Logging.logger[LIBRARY_GEM_LOGGER_ROOT_DEFAULT]

     Timeout::Error:
       execution expired
     Shared Example Group: "basic motion command" called from ./spec/lib/spectra_library/motion/motion_commander_spec.rb:80
     # ./lib/spectra_library/logging.rb:15:in `library_gem_logger'
     # ./lib/spectra_library/logging.rb:28:in `library_logger'
     # ./lib/spectra_library/logging.rb:35:in `library_motion_logger'
     # ./lib/spectra_library/motion/motion_commander.rb:150:in `block in exec_mc!'
     # ./lib/spectra_library/motion/motion_commander.rb:148:in `exec_mc!'
     # ./lib/spectra_library/motion/motion_commander.rb:95:in `gather'
     # ./spec/lib/spectra_library/motion/motion_commander_spec.rb:79:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/lib/spectra_library/motion/motion_commander_spec.rb:20:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.09762 seconds (files took 0.72568 seconds to load)
30 examples, 1 failure
```

```
Failures:

  1) SpectraLibrary::Motion::MotionCommander#drawer_to_drawer behaves like basic motion command with successful result should receive execute("/RCM_code/mc --drawertodrawer  --srcdrawer #<SpectraLibrary::Motion::HydraDrawer:0x000055710f024e20> --destdrawer #<SpectraLibrary::Motion::HydraDrawer:0x000055710f024d30> --force", *(any args)) 1 time
     Failure/Error: @library_gem_logger ||= ::Logging.logger[LIBRARY_GEM_LOGGER_ROOT_DEFAULT]

     Timeout::Error:
       execution expired
     Shared Example Group: "basic motion command" called from ./spec/lib/spectra_library/motion/motion_commander_spec.rb:42
     # ./lib/spectra_library/logging.rb:15:in `library_gem_logger'
     # ./lib/spectra_library/logging.rb:28:in `library_logger'
     # ./lib/spectra_library/logging.rb:35:in `library_motion_logger'
     # ./lib/spectra_library/motion/motion_commander.rb:150:in `block in exec_mc!'
     # ./lib/spectra_library/motion/motion_commander.rb:149:in `exec_mc!'
     # ./lib/spectra_library/motion/motion_commander.rb:29:in `drawer_to_drawer'
     # ./spec/lib/spectra_library/motion/motion_commander_spec.rb:41:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/lib/spectra_library/motion/motion_commander_spec.rb:20:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.08525 seconds (files took 0.75393 seconds to load)
30 examples, 1 failure
```

```
Failures:

  1) SpectraLibrary::Motion::MotionCommander#drawer_to_drawer behaves like basic motion command with successful result should receive execute("/RCM_code/mc --drawertodrawer  --srcdrawer #<SpectraLibrary::Motion::HydraDrawer:0x000055ef29d2efd8> --destdrawer #<SpectraLibrary::Motion::HydraDrawer:0x000055ef29d2ef38> --force", *(any args)) 1 time
     Failure/Error: @library_gem_logger ||= ::Logging.logger[LIBRARY_GEM_LOGGER_ROOT_DEFAULT]

     Timeout::Error:
       execution expired
     Shared Example Group: "basic motion command" called from ./spec/lib/spectra_library/motion/motion_commander_spec.rb:42
     # ./lib/spectra_library/logging.rb:15:in `library_gem_logger'
     # ./lib/spectra_library/logging.rb:28:in `library_logger'
     # ./lib/spectra_library/logging.rb:35:in `library_motion_logger'
     # ./lib/spectra_library/motion/motion_commander.rb:150:in `block in exec_mc!'
     # ./lib/spectra_library/motion/motion_commander.rb:149:in `exec_mc!'
     # ./lib/spectra_library/motion/motion_commander.rb:29:in `drawer_to_drawer'
     # ./spec/lib/spectra_library/motion/motion_commander_spec.rb:41:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/lib/spectra_library/motion/motion_commander_spec.rb:20:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.10332 seconds (files took 0.73916 seconds to load)
30 examples, 1 failure
```

Comment: Can you show the specs?

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of your issue, but according to docs, you can't rescue inside the timeout block unless you specify explicitly what exception to throw (2nd argument)  "The exception thrown to terminate the given block cannot be rescued inside the block unless klass is given explicitly." https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html

Comment: Oh, yeah why are you rescuing inside the timeout block? It makes more sense to do it outside.

Comment: I've tried rescuing both inside and outside of the timeout block with the same result. I'll add the specs now.

Comment: It would be better if you boiled down your example to sth more comprehensible. Like a single spec that is failing after adding the timeout. Also making it more understandable would help (e.g. inline some of the methods). You also define `stub_and_expect_mc` to accept 3 array attributes, and call it with an integer `stub_and_expect_mc(0)`.

Comment: Edited to add inlined method for the logger, but my problem is that the spec that happens to fail keeps changing. I'll add the last three times I ran specs to the question.